# How can I output GPIOs and SPIs in QEMU?

Tags: linux, arm, embedded, qemu, bare-metal

I want to output every I/O from an emulated ARM chip to the host. Is there a way to output 5 or so GPIOs and a few SPIs in QEMU?

As a side question, is there any way I can output 8 UARTs? I've seen ways to redirect up to 4 UARTs to /dev/* on a Linux host, but not 8.

Comment: In what form do you want to expose the I/O from the emulated board to your host? I'm not sure there exists a standard way to do that in qemu right now.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by form. What I want to do is emulate several independent chips and have them talk to each other, and to be able to debug what's going on in those chips. I thought the easiest way to do that would be to emulate 1 at a time and have them talk to each other via the host. That has not proven to be easy though.

Comment: Ok so basically you need a way to expose I/Os (digital, analog or even buses) for both input and output and it should be possible to connect these between instances of QEMU. I'm pretty sure this does not exist at the moment. But I suspect that could be seen as a nice addition to QEMU :-)

Comment: May I ask how it went for you? Did you i.e. added some code for each chip acting as virtual com etc? I was wondering if creation of such interfaces would be justified for future testing, or it would still be better to create test bench with the device.

Comment: My memory is a little fuzzy on the details at the moment... I eventually got 4 consoles working. The commands to do this wasn't too tough once I read a ton of example command lines (which I found less confusing than the docs). The tough part was there were several bugs in the QEMU code for the processor I was using: memory spaces were overlapping and breaking things, and it was hard-coded to only supporting one console for no apparent reason. I need to go back and look at exactly what I changed and submit my fix as a patch, I'll try to do that this afternoon.

Comment: After 2 patches for errors in memory and changing MAX_SERIAL_PORTS to 8, I was able to emulate all the UARTs I needed to make a test bench for our project. Then the project changed what processor they were using and I was moved to a different project.